# MUnit testing issue with apikit:config

Tags: maven, mule-esb

I am trying to run the MUnit through maven in command line using (mvn test), however i am getting the below error. Its is throwing error in line no -9 where apikit:config is configured. When i tried to run it using Anypoint studio it is working fine. Can someone please help me debugging the issue here.

Thanks in advance:) Nitesh

**Error logs-**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:maven-demo1.xml]
 Offending resource: URL [file:/N:/Mulesoft/Work1/maven-demo1/src/test/munit/maven-demo1-apikit-test.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from class path resource [maven-demo1.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 170; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'apikit:config'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
```

**Configuration.xml file--**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
     <http:listener-config xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" name="maven-demo1-httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
     <apikit:config xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" name="maven-demo1-config" raml="maven-demo1.raml" consoleEnabled="false" doc:name="Router"/>
     <flow name="maven-demo1-main">
         <http:listener xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" config-ref="maven-demo1-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
         <apikit:router xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" config-ref="maven-demo1-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
         <exception-strategy ref="maven-demo1-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
     </flow>
     <flow name="maven-demo1-console">
         <http:listener xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" config-ref="maven-demo1-httpListenerConfig" path="/console/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
         <apikit:console xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" config-ref="maven-demo1-config" doc:name="APIkit Console1"/>
     </flow>
     <sub-flow name="set-variable">
         <set-variable variableName="variable1" value="XYZ" doc:name="Variable"/>
     </sub-flow>
     <flow name="get:/maven:maven-demo1-config">
         <flow-ref name="set-variable" doc:name="set-variable"/>
         <set-payload value="{
   &quot;message&quot;: &quot;This is successful from Backend&quot;,
   &quot;code&quot;: 1010
 }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
     </flow>
     <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" name="maven-demo1-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
         <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
             <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException" />
             <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
             <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Resource not found&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </apikit:mapping>
         <apikit:mapping statusCode="405">
             <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.MethodNotAllowedException" />
             <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
             <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Method not allowed&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </apikit:mapping>
         <apikit:mapping statusCode="415">
             <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException" />
             <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
             <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Unsupported media type&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </apikit:mapping>
         <apikit:mapping statusCode="406">
             <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotAcceptableException" />
             <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
             <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Not acceptable&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </apikit:mapping>
         <apikit:mapping statusCode="400">
             <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.BadRequestException" />
             <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
             <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Bad request&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </apikit:mapping>
     </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
 </mule>
```

**POM.XMLfile contains below plugin--**

```
 <plugin>
         <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
         <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${munit.version}</version>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>test</id>
                 <phase>test</phase>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>test</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
             <coverage>
                 <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                 <formats>
                     <format>html</format>
                 </formats>
             </coverage>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check mule-module-apikit available or not, if not add it

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
       <version>${mule.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```